# Evade the Wizard...Which potion?

Tags: logical-deduction

You are a 10 year old kid from the 1620's. One day, you decide to explore a cool cave you found hidden behind moss and vines. Bad idea. It's a wizard's house, and his spell book is open to a page titled *Turning People Into Toads*. A cauldron of water is bubbling in the corner, next to an ingredient rack and a book of potions. There is a list of ingredients on top of the book, and the rack has three rows of seven bottles each. Suddenly, you hear the wizard coming. The door is enchanted, and you cannot escape. You flip the book open to *Pass Through Barriers*, and get ready to make the potion. Here is a list of ingredients:

> You will need the following:
>
> - Eye of Toad
> - Wing of Bat
> - Tail of Wildebeest
> - Hair of Goat
> - Powdered Copper
> - Essence of Pigflower
> - Dust of Ancient Bones

Seriously? How are you supposed to know what is what? There are 21 bottles, and you need 7 specific ones. The wizard is evil but wise, so he stores his ingredient locations in a puzzle. The puzzle also has a warning:

> There are a total of XXI ingredients. Please use caution, as the wrong one may cause explosions. The top shelf is reserved for powders, the middle shelf for essences and furs, and the bottom shelf for other. The bottles are made of clay, so take caution and do not spill them.

Each ingredient on the shelves gets a listing in the puzzle:

> - Lion's Mane is above Tail of Wildebeest, and right of Hair of Goat
> - Essence of Wildflower is above Eye of Toad and left of Essence of Lavender
> - Wing of Bat is somewhere to the left of Tail of Wildebeest
> - Oil of Vitriol is somewhere below Powdered Silver
> - Tail of Wildebeest is 3rd to the right
> - Powdered Limestone is right of the Dust of Ancient Bones
> - Dust of Crystal Ball is somewhere above Wing of Bat, and somewhere left of Powdered Iron
> - Essence of Lavender is below Powdered Limestone
> - Powdered Copper is left of Powdered Zinc
> - Powdered Iron is left of Powdered Copper
> - Powdered Silver is somewhere right of Powdered Copper
> - Powdered Zinc is with the Powdered Metals, which are all in the same row
> - Dust of Ancient Bones is above Essence of Wildflower
> - Hair of Goat is below Powdered Iron, and somewhere right of Essence of Wildflower
> - Essence of Pigflower is left of Essence of Wildflower
> - Mercury is on the shelf below Powdered Iron, and is somewhere right of Lion's Mane
> - Eye of Newt is below Essence of Lavender
> - Tail of Horse is below Powdered Zinc
> - Chicken Feet are somewhere right of Wing of Bat, and somewhere left of Tail of Giraffe
> - Eye of Toad is somewhere left of Oil of Vitriol
> - Tail of Giraffe is on the shelf below Essence of Lavender

You have a few minutes to quickly figure it out, since the wizard seems to be practicing vanishing his toothbrush. You can see him in the one-way mirror. Of course, you are a 10 year old boy, and have no idea what Eye of Newt or Oil of Vitriol is, so you can't just open the bottles and look at them. Quick: Which bottles are which?

Clarification:

"Left" and "Right" indicate directly left or directly right. "Somewhere to the left" would indicate any position to the left. "Shelf above" indicates, not that it is directly above, but instead that it is on the shelf above. Hope this helps.

Comment: Similar puzzle: https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/63187/a-grave-issue-discovered

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think I got this right, I highlighted the needed ingredients too:

> [image: Solution calc]

Comment: was about to post my answer till I noticed it was the same as yours. thief lol

Answer (score 3):

Here it is, I highlighted the needed ingredients as well:

> [image: potion]

Comment: According to ingredients, "Oil of Vitriol is somewhere below Powdered Silver" and "Dust of Crystal Ball is somewhere above Wing of Bat." Almost correct...thanks for highlighting the needed ingredients.

Comment: Some of those were my mistakes. I had accidentally put Eye of Toad as _right_ of Oil of Vitriol. Anyway, now it's fixed, and Eye of Toad is on the _left_.