# A Grave Issue Discovered

Tags: logical-deduction, logic-grid

In the town of Fairfield (There are 35 Fairfield's in America), there is a graveyard. In 1874, the mayor, Arthur Hither, declared that 25 new graves be created, in a square. Five years later, he was buried in the center. One day, a hurricane comes through and destroys the graves. The people are still buried, but nobody knows where everyone is. You put a hint box in the center of the city, and get these hints:

> - My grandfather was East of the mayor 1 spot
> - The police chief was 2 spots North of Mrs. Francine Hither
> - The mayor's family was in a row of 3 plots going East to West
> - The mayor's mom, Mrs. Francine Hither, is just East of one of the old professors
> - The first note was by Holly Hither
> - There are three old professors. One, Prof. Tasker, is next to the Police Chief
> - Mr. Henry Carpenter is South of Officer Smith
> - Every doctor has a professor on the far West of him
> - The Army Captain is somewhere South of Mr. and Mrs. Williams
> - The doctors, Dr. Oak, Dr. Birch, and Dr. Cedar, are all North of Oliver Twist's grave
> - The Old Millionaire is South of the Evil Villain
> - The Evil Villain is West of Ms. Johnson
> - Mr. Mackarel is a few graves South of the mayor's mom
> - Prof. Rathburne and Dr. Oak are across from each other
> - Dr. Birch is next to Mr. Williams, and Mrs. Williams is West of Dr. Oak
> - Ms. Sarah Williams is West of her mom
> - Mr. Crabapple is buried South of the Police Chief
> - Mr. Crabapple is Southwest of the Fire Chief by one space, and is one space West of Sarah
> - The Evil Villain is South of Professor Vocab
> - The Army Captain has Arthur Z. on his East side, and Mr. Mackarel two spots West
> - I remember someone named Nancy Smith

With these hints, you think you can rebuild the gravestones, and get a huge payment from the city. You have no advanced technology available, and the city says you can't dig up the people to find out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The layout of the graves is

> [image]

In text format (row by row):

Row 1

> Prof Tasker......./  Police Chief...../ Fire Chief........../ Mr. Williams......./ Dr. Birch

Row 2

> Prof Rathburne./ Mr. Crabapple../ Sarah Williams / Mrs Williams....../ Dr. Oak

Row 3

> Prof Vocab......./ Francine Hither / Mayor Hither..../ Holly Hithers GF/ Dr. Cedar

Row 4

> Evil Villian......../ Ms Johnson....../ Officer Smith...../ Nancy Smith...../ Oliver Twist

Row 5

> Old Millionaire../ Mr. Mackarel..../ Henry Carpenter/ Army Captain.../ Arthur Z

I apologize for the formatting, but I was having problems posting an image so this is the "brute force" way of showing the layout.  If anyone can see my image through the link and edit it in, I would greatly appreciate it.

One possible alternate:

> If the statement "The Evil Villain is West of Ms. Johnson" means that the Evil Villain must be *immediately* West of Ms. Johnson, then this is the only solution (as far as I know).  If the EV can be anywhere West of Ms. Johnson, then her grave and Nancy Smith's could be switched.

Comment: Just realized that StackExchange pictures don't load on my computer

Comment: OK - maybe the problem is on your end instead of mine.  In case the image didn't load, I added my solution in text.